# How to Change Date Formate Ajax codeigniter Recording Listing..?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

How to Change Date formate in codeigniter ajax listing.When I am get Records from database with ajax.I want to change my date formate to DD/MM/YYYY.

View Page Listing Code:-

```
             for (i = 0; i < o.all2; i++)
                        {   

                            count2 += 1;
                            output2 += '<tr class="new_tr2">';
                            output2 += '<td>' + count2 + '</td>' +
                                    // '<td>' + o.activity2[i]['student_name'] +'</td>'+
                                    '<td>' + o.activity2[i]['name'] + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + o.activity2[i]['date_time'] + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + o.activity2[i]['note'] + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + res+ '</td>'+
                                    '<td>' +button+'</td>';
                            output2 += '</tr>';

                        }
                        $('#app4').append(output2);
```

[image]

Comment: you  can use date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date)) function of php at server side

Answer (score 0):

I am using this javascript function in formatting my date.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [day, month, year].join('/');
}
```

Comment: Then i am use this function like  formateDate(o.activity2[i]['date_time'])

Comment: Yes something like that.